# Routing with gRPC microservices and Kubernetes

Tags: apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc

I have two applications one is a regular Kafka consumer and the other is a gRPC based microservice. Kafka consumer is only responsible for consumption of messages and the business logic resides within the microservice. Also the key for messages within our Kafka topic is null, so Kafka does round-robin assignment of messages to the partitions which distributes the incoming messages evenly to all partitions. At the end of the day I am dealing with non-transactional storage (BigTable) so I have to make sure that there is only one thread responsible for reading, updating and writing a row-key into the storage in order to avoid race-conditions. My gRPC microservice is running within a Kubernetes cluster on multiple pods, how can I make sure that a message object belonging to a particular row-key goes to the same pod within the Kubernetes cluster so that there are no race-conditions?? My microservice is responsible for writing the final output to the BigTable and the microservice is sitting behind a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a solution if you already have a (big) code base, but streaming frameworks like [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) handle this pretty gracefully.

It has an operator [keyBy()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/operators/) that does exactly what you want. It will 'sort' the messages by a key defined by you and will guarantee messages with the same key get processed by the same thread.